# Azure Function Hybrid connection to share folder

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hybrid-connections

I would like to know your advice on the below scenario:

We have Azure Function (not durable function) and output of the function spouse to create a file and copy it to VM folder (a shared folder on VM) on the same subscription. Express route V NET already configured.

Can you please advise how this can be configured?

BTW, we don't want to use ASE.. and logic apps. Thanks for the reply.

Regards,
DK.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

Map a folder in your vm pointing to Azure Files:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows

and create files on it using regular c# with Azure Storage SDK:

```
CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference(DemoDirectory);
await dir.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference(ImageToUpload);
await file.UploadFromFileAsync(ImageToUpload, FileMode.Open);
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Samples/GettingStarted/VisualStudioQuickStarts/DataFileStorage/Program.cs

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. But my question was not to add a mapped drive in VM and access it from Azure Function but I need to access C drive program file and sub folder.. e.g. C:\Program Files\App\Data